# Android package for accessing 5 GHz wifi information like RSSI?

Tags: wi-fi

Is there a package file for android that I can access information of WiFi operating at 5 GHz. information like scanning the wifi networks available in 5 GHz bands, accessing RSSI of all the APs operating in 5ghz band?

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) One more pointer, though: you might check the network section of [my app listings](http://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists.php), should make your search easier ;)

Answer (score 4):

[Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) is a great app for viewing wifi information

[image]